# White screen on rotate cordova/android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Does anyone know how to get rid of this. (White screen on rotate)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwsmoq6owq29cgu/screenrecording.mp4?dl=0

Only happens on Android phones, tested with Note 4(Android 5.0), Galaxy S5, Moto G.
This happens with every ionic/cordova sample codes.

Ionic Version : "1.0.0"

Cordova : 3.6.4

my Meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

also my in my android manifest:

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                   android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:name=".TelerikCallbackActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                  android:launchMode="standard"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="user" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      </application>
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```